# Align UILabel Size Inside UICollectionView Programatically

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

I am using UICollectionView in my application. Problem is I am having multiple UILabel's inside UICollectionView. Width of UILabel is more than collectionview width. So Its get overlapped and not looking good. How to set width of collectionview label programatically

Comment: `UILabel` inside `UICollectionView`, you mean in a `UICollectionViewCell`? Could you gave screenshot of your issue, and some code maybe? Do you use NSLayoutConstraints?

Comment: show your tried code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the Auto layout approach with constraints or using frames here's how the code would look in Objective-C:

```
// using auto layout
self.label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.label
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:self.contentView
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                multiplier:0.8
                                                  constant:0]];


//using frames
CGFloat labelWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.bounds)*0.8;
self.label.frame = CGRectMake(DESIRED_X_POSSITION, DESIRED_Y_POSSITION, labelWidth, DESIRED_HEIGHT);

// you can set your labels' number of lines to 0 so your text goes to the next line
self.label.numberOfLines = 0
```